sharepoint online/cloud requires any patching?
I had discussion with 2 IT admins - based on that and my knowledge SP Online does not require any action from us(IT) in patching matters. This info was passed to another IT director and he is still stating that from time to time Microsoft requires any action from the IT to update some SharePoint security stuff - I am working in SP Online for maybe 5 years and never I was involved in that kind of actions - everything came from Microsoft automatically.
On prem that is another thing and it is clear:)

SharePoint Online does not require manual patching. Microsoft pushes the updates automatically, based on the release options.
However, many updates pushed by Microsoft require your attention. For example:

One of the updates disabled SharePoint 2010 workflows in SPO.
Another update will disable Workflow 2013 engine in 2026.
In 2015 the support for the public-facing SharePoint Online sites was removed.
etc.

There are lots of other examples. So, while you don't need to patch anything yourself, you need to keep an eye on the Upcoming changes in the M365 Admin center.

Excellent COmment! Thanks! Upcoming changes in the M365 are visible for Global Admin only or SharePoint admin as well?

If you only have the SharePoint admin role, then you can see SharePoint-specific messages on the home page, in the Message center
https://TENANT-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/home
You should also be able to access the M365 Admin portal: "https://admin.microsoft.com", but I am not 100% sure if you will see the upcoming changes tab on its home page.

SharePoint Online does not require patching but it does require constant monitoring and testing of the new features that Denis mentioned.
Make sure you are well aware of the coming changes, inform your users when necessary and test all your customizations in DEV (where you should have Preview Release) before the changes come to Production environment.
Some of the changes that Denis mentioned may have Action Required that usually involves disabling the feature that is coming or assessing its impact on your organization, e.g.

[Microsoft Intune] Plan for Change: Microsoft Intune ending support for User Enrollment with Company Portal for iOS/iPadOS [MC810406]
[What you need to do to prepare:] Use an alternate management method
for enrolling devices.


SharePoint online is controlled by Microsoft and it does not require patching.
You also could go to the Microsoft 365 admin center -> Health -> Service health and Message center to check information about SharePoint.
